# Plotting time in matplotlib for every 10 min interval

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image: Result of the graph]I'm new to matplotlib, and i would like to ask for your help.

The problem is that the graph that I want to plot is giving me an interval for a year, and i only need it to plot for every 10 min interval for each day.

As of now, there is only 1 value for time which is 12:00:00. But as you can see you can not know that in my current graph :( can you teach me guys how to do it.

```
#The time variable is an array filled populated with time strings like ['11:55:53', '11:55:54', '11:55:54' ... ]
#The bandwidth variable is just populated with integers
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime
import time as t
import matplotlib.dates as dt
import numpy as np

def DownloadGraph(bandwidth, time, host) :
x = []
y = bandwidth
last = []
for this in range(len(time)):
    x.append(datetime.strptime(time[this], '%I:%M:%S').time())    
fig = plt.figure() #for modifying the graph details
rect = fig.patch
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1, axisbg = 'yellow') 
ax1.plot(x,y, 'blue',linewidth=1.6)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand your question correctly. But if you want to set the date-tick-positions or the displayed format of the dates, then you should have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27985176/3852024. The timespan to plot can be adjusted with: ax1.set_xlim(min, max)

Comment: Sorry zinjaai, the image didnt upload with the post, here is the image. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What values have the x and y variable at the time of plotting? Without this information its very difficult to help you.

Comment: y = [74, 102, 74, 102, 74]

x = [ datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0) ]

The result just goes on like that, the result is like that because im plotting the average bandwidth usage of a host in a 10 min interval and i just need to display it in a graph.

zinjaai, i actually followed the link you gave me. I was able to display the time already however, it is not the result i was looking for but im a step closer. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your x axis is that all values are identical.
Since matplotlib doesn't know in which range of x-values you're interested - it defaults to +- 2 years.

As soon as you have more than one unique x value, the range will be set from the minumum to maximum.
With different x-values your posted y-values would look like:

```
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
y = [74, 102, 74, 102, 12]
x = [datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0),
     datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 5, 0),
     datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 10, 0),
     datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 15, 0),
     datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 2, 20, 0)]

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

To realize a increase of 10 minutes per index you could adjust your for loop in a way like:

```
for idx, this_time in enumerate(time):
    x.append(datetime.strptime(this_time, '%I:%M:%S').time()) + datetime.timedelta(minutes=10*idx)
```